# Shouldn't my nhibernate mapping take care of this? Error: not-null property reference a null or transient value

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, many-to-many

I have a database with 3 tables:

1. Project
2. Sponsor
3. ProjectSponsor

In my domain objects, i have an object **Project** which has a child property called **Sponsors** which is a list of **ProjectSponsor** objects, like this:

```
 IList<ProjectSponsor> Sponsors;
```

here is the **Nhibernate Mapping code**:

**ProductMap**:

```
HasMany(x => x.Sponsors).AsBag().Inverse().Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
```

**ProductSponsorMap:**

```
References(x => x.Project).Not.Nullable();
References(x => x.Sponsor).Not.Nullable();
```

here is **my Domain Objects**:

```
public class Project
{
    public virtual IList<ProjectSponsor> Sponsors { get; set; }
}

 public class ProjectSponsor
{
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
    public virtual Sponsor Sponsor { get; set; }
}
```

ok . . now to my issue, when i try to add new Projects (with their associated projectsponsor) into the database.

Here is my code:

```
    foreach (Project project in newProjects)
   {
      Repository.Save(project);
      foreach (ProjectSponsor projectSponsor in project.Sponsors)
      {
           Repository.Save(projectSponsor);
      }
   }
```

I am getting an exception on this line:

```
     Repository.Save(projectSponsor);
```

saying that **not-null property reference a null or transient value is trying to be saved**:

projectSponsor.Project is the property that its complaining about.  I would have thought that would be set by default based on the nhibernate mapping.

do i really need to have an explicit piece of code that have this code:

```
projectSponsor.Project = project
```

or is there anything wrong with my mapping files ?

Comment: Is there more to ProjectSponser? If not, you should map the relationship as many-to-many.

Comment: @Jamie Ide - there isn't more to ProjectSponsor. Its simply a bridge class between Projects and Sponsors.  how would i do many to many with fluent nhibernate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't set the `projectSponsor.Project` property (and no code here says you have) then it will have the default value of null which will violate the mapping condition you've placed.

NHibernate is just going to reflect the state of the objects and the state of the objects is - for want of a better word - broken as is. You could remove the Project property on the ProjectSponsor map and all would be well but you're losing functionality to do so because obviously the directionality of relationships in OO is the reverse of RDBM directionality.

I would expect something like:

```
public class ProjectSponsor 
{     
    // This is how you instantiate me!
    public ProjectSponsor(Project project, Sponsor sponsor)
    {
        this.Project = project;
        this.Sponsor = sponsor;
    }

    protected ProjectSponsor()
    {
        // I exist for NHibernates benefit only!
    }

    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }     

    public virtual Sponsor Sponsor { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: if i remove the project property of the ProjectSponsor map would it still save correctly in the ProjectSponsor table ?? How would it know what to persist in the projectId column of the ProjectSponsor table

Comment: No, it most likely wouldn't because you probably have an appropriate NOT NULL FK on the column in your DB. The correct thing to do is to set the property to it's parent (or better, make the parent an argument of the constructor). Sorry if I confused you I was just trying to illustrate the problem (and failing).

Answer (score 0):

You should map this as a many-to-many relationship. To do this, delete ProjectSponsor from the model and map the collections using HasManyToMany. For the project map:

```
HasManyToMany(X => x.Sponsors).Table("ProjectSponsor")
    .ParentKeyColumn("ProjectId").ChildKeyColumn("SponsorId")
    .AsBag().LazyLoad();
```

and similarly for Sponsor:

```
HasManyToMany(X => x.Projects).Table("ProjectSponsor")
    .ParentKeyColumn("SponsorId").ChildKeyColumn("ProjectId")
    .Inverse().AsBag().LazyLoad();
```

Note that I marked Sponsor as the inverse side of the relationship but it could be Project. With these changes you just need to add a Sponsor to the Project's Sponsor collection for it to be persisted. I recommend exposing an AddSponsor method rather than accessing the collection directly.

However, I think you've got another problem. It appears to me that you're following the anti-pattern of having your repository classes control the ISession. One of (the many) reasons this is a bad pattern is that your saves appear to be executed immediately instead of in a transaction.

Comment: thanks .  i have another case where the bridge table also has additional fields like Pct Allocated.  What would you do in that case as the many to many wont factor in these additional columns

Comment: For a many-to-many with additional data, you do have to model it as two one-to-many relationships and include the object representing the link in your domain model.

Comment: ok so just for full clarification, lets assume that ProjectSponsor has another field, what would be the answer to the question ??

Comment: @ooo - If ProjectSponsor had an additional field then it would be mapped as two one-to-many relationships similar to what you have now.